# ie11 jquery width() returning wrong value

Tags: jquery, width, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

i have a `div` i know to be large exactly `1004px`.
I need this value to be extracted in a variable to use in javascript:

```
var siteWidth = $(".large-8.columns").width();
```

this results in 1004.8px in ie10-11

[image]

I've tried using this to detect the width of the element instead:

```
$(".large-8.columns")[0].getBoundingClientRect().width
```

but it gives an even weirder numer: `1013.91998px`

Do you have any idea of what's going on? This breaks my layout

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect` gets the union of all CSS borders of an element, so it's adding width to the actual width of the element. What's wrong with that extra .8 pixel? Can't you just drop the decimal and there's your 1004?

Comment: that size is key to a two-column layout in pixels. that extra .8px is breaking it.

Comment: Why not just drop the decimal with `Math.floor()`?